# Random variable $X$ is uniform $(−1,1)$, what is the value of : $P(−0.5 ≤ X < 1.5)$

Tags: calculus, probability

I solved it using 
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1/2, &(-1, 1);\\ 0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

And, to find the value I used integral of $1/2$ with boundaries: $-0.5$ to $1.5$

My question is should I include $1.5$ into the integral or use 1 instead because I have $P(−0.5 ≤ X < 1.5)$, where $1.5$ is not in the interval.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the integral from $-0.5$ to $1.5$ but the integrand $f(x)$ will be zero between $1$ and $1.5$

$$\int_{-0.5}^{1.5} f(x)\, dx = \int_{-0.5}^{1} \frac12\, dx+\int_{1}^{1.5} 0\, dx$$

Comment: thanks, got it!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $P(-1 \leq X \leq 1) = 1$. Thus

$$P(-0.5 \leq X \leq 1.5) = P(-0.5 \leq X \leq 1) + P(1 < X \leq 1.5)$$$$= P(-0.5 \leq X \leq 1) = 3/4$$

If you understand the uniform distribution, there is no need to calculate an integral.

Comment: understood, thank you!